# Check/Uncheck all the checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have not enough knowledge about jQuery,I need one more checkbox by the name "select all". When I select this checkbox all checkboxes in the HTML page must be selected. How can I do this?

I am using below code but it does not works fine :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="listbox.css" />
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
// Listen for click on toggle checkbox
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
    if(this.checked) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;                        
        });
    }
});
</script>

</head>

<body>


<label for="blah">item-1</label> <input name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" />    
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" />

</body>
</html>
```

I've download jQ from blow link :

http://jquery.com/download/

Download the compressed, production jQuery 2.1.1

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js

Comment: You aren't binding any event because at time code is processed, no element is in DOM. Use e.g document ready handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <ul>
      <li><label>item-1</label><input name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" class="checkitem" /></li> 
      <li><label>item-1</label><input name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" class="checkitem"  /></li> 
      <li><label>item-1</label><input name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" class="checkitem"  /></li> 
      <li><label>item-1</label><input name="checkbox-4" id="checkbox-4" type="checkbox" class="checkitem"  /></li> 
    </ul>
    <input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" /> Check all

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#select-all').click(function(event) {  
            if(this.checked) { 
                $('.checkitem').each(function() { 
                    this.checked = true;     
                });
            }else{
                $('.checkitem').each(function() {
                    this.checked = false; 
                });        
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9o3f01e0/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {
   var checked = this.checked; 
   $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
     $(this).prop('checked', checked);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the fiddle i made][1]

Add script at the bottom of page

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/zbjc0fpe/1/
```

Comment: sorry i thought, you only want to do for checking. Let me update fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Just for grins and giggles...the other answers work find, but I like the concise-ness and re-usability of the following method...so just in case this helps anyone:

```
$(document).on('click','[data-toggle=checkAll]', function() {
    var $all     = $(this),
        $targets = $( $all.data('target') )
    ;
    $targets.prop('checked', $all.is(':checked') );
}
```

Using the above script, you can have as many "checkAll" checkboxes on the page as you want...each "check all" checkbox just needs to specify a different target selector:

```
<input type='checkbox' data-toggle='checkAll' data-target='.check-option' /> check all
<input type='checkbox' class='check-option' value='1' /> option 1
<input type='checkbox' class='check-option' value='2' /> option 2

<input type='checkbox' data-toggle='checkAll' data-target='.check-option2' /> check all 2
<input type='checkbox' class='check-option2' value='1' /> option 1
<input type='checkbox' class='check-option2' value='2' /> option 2
```