# Check\Uncheck all the items in the List - Visual Studio LightSwitch

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using Visual Studio LightSwitch 2015

I have added `Countries` Table from SQL Server and for each `Country` in the List, I have `CheckBox`

Now I have placed a `CheckBox` at the top of the List Using `Custom Control`

```
myapp.Countries.CheckAll_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {

var checkbox = $("<input type='checkbox'/>")
        .css({
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
            left:-26,
            margin: "45px"
        })
        .appendTo($(element));
```

};

**How can I `Select\DeSelect All` the CheckBoxes in the List with single Click of the `CheckBox` at the top of the Table?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the above code example works, you can actually do it faster assuming the checkboxes you want to check are the only ones on the page (besides the "check all" checkbox).

The below checks all checkboxes on the page except the "Check All" one.

```js
 $("#checkAll").click(function () {
     $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">Check All
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem">Item 1
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem">Item 2
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem">Item3
```

Comment: The jquery script works perfectly in the current scenario. But the thing is if there is any other checkbox with different name and purpose, even that checkbox will also get checked on click of `#checkAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example from this post [Check/Uncheck all the checkboxes in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938032/check-uncheck-all-the-checkboxes-in-jquery)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#select-all').click(function(event) {  
            if(this.checked) { 
                $('.checkitem').each(function() { 
                    this.checked = true;     
                });
            }else{
                $('.checkitem').each(function() {
                    this.checked = false; 
                });        
            }
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li><label>item-1</label><input name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" class="checkitem" /></li> 
      <li><label>item-1</label><input name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" class="checkitem"  /></li> 
      <li><label>item-1</label><input name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" class="checkitem"  /></li> 
      <li><label>item-1</label><input name="checkbox-4" id="checkbox-4" type="checkbox" class="checkitem"  /></li> 
    </ul>
    <input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" /> Check all
```

Comment: In which event I have to write in VS LightSwitch?

Comment: Are you asking where to put this Javascript code? You should add it to your scripts folder or follow the documentation from this page: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dbd951/how-data-binding-works-in-visual-studio-lightswitch-html-cli/